# AddStore doesn't work in visual studio 2010 but works in visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, outlook

I have a C# application to process PST files. But the application works properly in visual studio 2012 but won't run in visual studio 2010.

```
        var outLookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        var outLookSession = outLookApp.Session;
        outLookSession.AddStore(pstFilePath); //
```

Getting this exception in visual studio 2010

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException occurred
>   HResult=-2147467259   Message=The Outlook data file (.pst) failed to
>   load for this session.   Source=Microsoft Outlook
>   ErrorCode=-2147467259   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass.AddStore(Object Store)
>          at Presensoft.PstImport.PstHelper.GetPstDetails(String pstFilePath, Int32& noOfItems, DateTime& dateOfOldestEmail, DateTime&
>   dateOfLatestEmail) in F:\PresensoftNewTrunk\Trunk\Email
>   Archiver\Tools\Presensoft.EmailImport\PstHelper.cs:line 15
>   InnerException:

Comment: Outlook does not know or care whether it is being invoked from code compiled in VS 2010 or 2012. What is the value of pstFilePath?

Comment: it's same in both cases.

Comment: And its value is? Is it a fully qualified file name that includes the full path?

Comment: Yup it's a FQN and its values is "F:\\OutlookData\\input\\test\\test1.pst". It's a same solution that i am opening from both visual studio with same app.config. Path is configured in app.config.